# Prevent Firebase from sending "Email address change" when linkWithCredential get called

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

When my app calls `linkWithCredential` Firebase sends an email titled "Your sign-in email was changed" automatically.
This happens when an user enters the email address different from the current one.
Is there any way to prevent Firebase from sending such email?

I'm trying with firebase v9.10.0 npm package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message is sent to the user's current email address to alert them to the change of their sign-in method/credentials. There is no way to control whether Firebase sends this email on calling the `linkWithCredential` API.

I recommend looking at the flow of your code, as wanting to suppress this message typically means that you're doing something unexpected. For example, if you know the user's current email address, it's probably better to detect when they enter a different value before calling the Firebase API, and ask them to confirm the value.